# Different ways to choose roles

Tags: roles

I am new to Snowflake and I just created a new 30 day free trial account.
Attached is a screenshot of Snowflake UI.
I don't understand the difference between choosing a role in the upper right corner (red marking in the screenshot) and choosing a role underneath it (green circle).
Thanks
Yoram[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controls in the green circle give the context in which sql in that specific sheet will be executed.

The controls in the red circle provide access control to the UI. For example, if you use the ACCOUNTADMIN role you'll see the Account icon but if you use the SYSADMIN role you won't.